# Why is "(1/6)*(66.900009-62.852596)" evaluating to zero?

Tags: python, xcode

Tried in both Objective-C (Xcode) and Python (terminal) and `(1/6)*(66.900009-62.852596)` evaluates to zero both times. Anyone know why this is? Shouldn't it be 0.26246?

Comment: Note that in Python 3.x, this isn't true. `/` is true division by default, so you get the expected result. You can also emulate this in Python 2.x by doing `from __future__ import division`.

Comment: Just FYI, and in addition to the answers below, you don't even need the trailing zeroes: `(1./6)` or `(1/6.)` will work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are doing integer arithmetic on `1/6`, and the floor of `1/6` is `0`.  Try `1.0/6` instead.

Answer (score 3):

`1/6` is integer division, which becomes 0. Try using `1.0/6` instead.

Answer (score 2):

The avoid doing accidental floor division with integer imports, do a `from __future__ import division` at the top of your module:

```
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> (1/6)*(66.900009-62.852596)
0.6745688333333331
```

The [future module](http://docs.python.org/library/__future__.html) is responsible for enabling features that will be turned out by default in Python 3.